# Batch Script to Loop through directory and fetch file name and concatenate the names to a string

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I need to prepare a batch file using a batch script to
1) Loop through files (.csv) files in a given directory and just take out the name of CSV file
2) Use this csv file name and concatenate with some string like below

```
"String1" "File Name1"
"String2"
"String1" "File Name2"
"String2"
"String1" "File Name3"
"String2"
```

3) redirect this output to another batch file.

Am new to creating batch scripts. Can any one here help me with an idea to create the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

**EDIT :**

```
@echo off
set $string="TOTO"
set $string2="TATA"
set "$Path=c:\test\"

pushd %$Path%
(for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    echo %%~dpnxa %$string%
    echo %$string2%))>Output.txt
popd
```

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to bring the "String2" that i had mentioned in my question to bring into a new line and then redirect all the output to that file?

Comment: Very Sorry. i need to take out the whole path and not just the filename. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Re EDIT for the full path

Comment: Great!! That really worked. Thanks a lot. One more question. Is it possible to strip of "" in "TATA" and then print it?

Comment: You can declare it without `"`. `set $string2=TATA` or use `echo %$string2:1,-1%`